# Generic conditional type resolves to never when the generic type is set to never

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-types

I need to have a generic type that excludes a generic property from a specified type when the generic parameter (of this property) is `never`. To achieve this I used `Omit` and conditional types. When the generic parameter is, for example, set to `number` it behaves as expected but when the generic type is set to `never`, the type resolves to `never` instead of excluding the specified property ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgFXBAPMgfFAvFAbwCgpSowAnAezAEYAuKBYCgSwDsBzAbhLM4jsACtTqNkvAL68ioSFACiADwDGAGwCuAEwhbMOXH1LIoEJcEFaEUdhABuEClAD8UAPIBbVsHTwkqSH0AGigAIgFhUVpQnEY-FDR9GRUqdmYoKgAjACsGRVVNHT12DQ9MxwNCIygIkRo8gFYg6sp6xlDMtThQomkiIhS04AycgCZGZXVtXXRbBwpK4jJyKPatAHctOA2e6SA)):

```
type BaseType<T> = {
  prop1: string;
  genProp1: T;
};

type Excluded<T> = T extends never ? Omit<BaseType<T>, "genProp1"> : BaseType<T>;

const obj1: Excluded<number> = {
  genProp1: 5,
  prop1: "something, something"
};

//obj2 is never
const obj2: Excluded<never> = {
  prop1: "dark side" //error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
};
```

Why does it do that and how can I make it return the correct type (`{ prop1: string }`)?

**EDIT:** comparing to `null` instead of `never` solves the issue. I would still like to know what's happening when I use `never`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Conditional types distribute over naked type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). This means that the conditional type gets applied to each member of the union. `never` is seen as the empty union. So the conditional type never gets applied (since there are no members in the union to apply it to) resulting in the `never` type.

The simple solution is to disable the distributive behavior of conditional types using a tuple:

```
type BaseType<T> = {
    prop1: string;
    genProp1: T;
};

type Excluded<T> =
    [T] extends [never] ? Omit<BaseType<T>, "genProp1"> : BaseType<T>;

const obj1: Excluded<number> = {
    genProp1: 5,
    prop1: "bla"
};

const obj2: Excluded<never> = {
    prop1: "dwdadw"
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=16&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgFXBAPMgfFAvFAbwCgpSowAnAezAEYAuKBYCgSwDsBzAbhLM4jsACtTqNkvAL68ioSFACiADwDGAGwCuAEwhbMOXH1IBtZAF0oEJcEFaEUY+wgA3CBQsB+KAHkAtq2B0eCRUSH0AGigAIgFhUVoonEZglDR9GRUqdmYoKgAjACsGRVVNHT12DV88twNCIyhYkRpigFZwhsoWxii8tTgoomkiIkzs4FzCgCZGZXVtXXQnVwo64jJyeJ6tAHctOF3B6SA)

Comment: OK, it makes sense now. Do you have an idea about the performance or "subtle issues" between using your solution and using `null` instead of `never` (see my edit above)?

Comment: @AndreiV depends what you want the behavior to be when `T` contains `null`. The version with `null` would remove `null` from `genProp1`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgFXBAPMgfFAvFAbwCgpSowAnAezAEYAuKBYCgSwDsBzAbhLM4jsACtTqNkvAL68ioSFACiADwDGAGwCuAEwhbMOXH1IBtZAF0oEJcEFaEUY+wgA3CBQsB+KAHkAtq2B0eCRUSH0AGigAIgFhUVoonEZglDR9GRUqdmYoKgAjACsAJkZldW1ddGY2LigAHyh2DV88t3rG5taKdqa1NQNCIyhYkRoGDr7wocoxxiitAHctOEWoomkiWTRFVU0dLQA5DT79PCHkS2tbe161KC8-AKDEVLDsSJjBUbpEqGSX0IYbAZLI5fIFADMpV2FUOxzU6FuPU6bgGxDIwy+8UYt0iAHo8ZYKMTptjootlqt1twgA

Comment: Hmm, I see... In my particular case, this is not an issue, since the properties would be either completely excluded or set to (most probably) a `string`.